# Changes in mainwindow.ui

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Why changes are not visible when I edit my mainwindow.ui file on my BeagleBone?
[image]

It shows only objects I define in mainwindow.cpp, but not when I use QT designer.

Did I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if there is a bad error in the ui file and it fails to compile.  I've had this happen to me once, and I ended up having to revert my ui file back to a previous version.  Maybe it might say something about it in your compile output tab.

Other things to try include:

- Build clean
- Delete the `Makefile` and `Makefile.*` files.
- Delete the `/release` and `/debug` directories.
- Run `qmake`

Also make sure that there aren't errors in your `.pro` file.

Also make sure you are accessing your objects in your ui file through the ui object.

```
ui->centralWidget();
ui->myLabel->setText("Hello World");
```

Hope that helps.